# Override Django ModelForm ImageField Widget attribute href -- FAIL

Tags: django, django-forms

From my previous ModelForm experience I should be able to override widget attributes in the form's constructor. This is not for the admin but for a template.

However, I have a field called "logo" in my model which is an ImageField. When I try to override the "href" attribute in the constructor it doesn't work...it only returns the normal url instead of the altered one I wanted to pass (see code below):

Is there a workaround for this?

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ResourceUserModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['user'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['state'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['ideal_candidate'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['logo'].widget.attrs['href'] = os.path.join( "media", self.instance.logo.url )
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This would create a `<input type="file" href="FOO" />` which.. is invalid.